# Interchanging remote hosting with computer hosting vs. displaying availability state of computer hosting on remote website

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosting, availability

Recently, I bought a domain kkziomek.eu. The root domain is **hosted on a remote hosting**. I added a subdomain "komputer.kkziomek.eu" which is **hosted on my computer**. To do that I created a subdomain, then edited the "A Record" to redirect on my computer IP, where I have a server set up. It works!

Now, my only question is:

I want to make a subdirectory on my **root website** "kkziomek.eu/komp/index.php" which would say in big letters "ONLINE" when my **computer and server on it is turned on**, and in big letters "OFFLINE" **when my computer, or server on my computer is off.**

So in other words, it would say "ONLINE" when "komputer.kkziomek.eu" is available, and "OFFLINE" when "komputer.kkziomek.eu" is not available.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in "kkziomek.eu/komp/index.php"

```
<?php
$host = 'komputer.kkziomek.eu';
if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
echo 'ONLINE!';
fclose($socket);
} else {
echo 'OFFLINE.';
}
?>
```